# Evolution and Chrome hang on start - Keyring problem?

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, evolution, keyrings, auto-login

Recently, Evolution and Chrome started hanging whenever I try to start them.

I believe the problem has to do with the gnome-keyring: I use Ubuntu 20.04.3 with auto-login. Because of this, my login keyring is not unlocked at login, and applications like Chrome and Evolution that depend on it *should* generate a password prompt. Usually they do, but as of a few days ago they don't, so they hang and I can't use either one.

When this happens, I am also unable to unlock the keyring via Seahorse: Opening Seahorse, going to Login, and pressing "Unlock" does nothing. Syslog shows no significant differences between starting Seahorse when it works and starting Seahorse when it doesn't work.

The keyring daemon appears to be running:

```
[username@machine]:~$ ps -fe | grep key
[username]         941       1  0 08:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
```

So I'm guessing that the issue has to do with communication between Evolution/Chrome and the keyring instead.

My understanding is that this is handled via DBus. [This page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingDBus) suggests using dbus-monitor for troubleshooting. From a single start of Evolution, dbus-monitor generates 550k of output, which I am at a loss to interpret. The only thing I did note is that the word "key" appears nowhere in it.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what the problem may be? Or how to filter dbus-monitor to reduce noise? I get the gist of filtering in dbus-monitor, but I'm not sure what type, sender, etc. to filter for.

Thank you.

Comment: I have no answer for you (and I hope someone else will), but here's a workaround: run Chrome with `--password-store=basic`, to disable trying to store passwords in gnome-keyring. See also here: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/152645

Comment: Thanks @GregPrice. I wish there were a comparable solution for Evolution.